# sql if statement checking for null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a county parameter, which if it's null, then I want to select all counties in the collaboration, if it's not null then I just want values for that one county.  How can I set up the `IF` statement correctly?  The first part of the `IF` statement may bring back multiple county Ids, which is why I put the `WHERE CountyId` in.

```
SELECT a.CountyId, co.Description as County
FROM Application as a
    INNER JOIN Dictionary.Counties as co on a.CountyId = co.Id
WHERE co.Id in 
    IF @pCountyId is null then 
    BEGIN
        SELECT cc1.CountyId 
        FROM CountyCollaboration as cc1
        WHERE cc1.CollaborationId = (SELECT cc2.CollaborationId
                FROM CountyCollaboration as cc2
                WHERE cc2.CountyId = @pHiddenCountyId)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pCountyId
    END
```

Comment: Deja Vu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846636/sql-if-statement-checking-for-null-parameter/

Comment: this is different.  If the countyId is null, then it uses HiddenCountyId for the collaboration.  If countyId is not null, then it uses just that CountyId

Comment: Just apply the same logic. `WHERE (@pCountyId IS NULL AND  co.Id in (...)) OR co.ID = @pCountyId`

Comment: that worked, thanks.  Just had the syntax a little off.

Comment: You're welcome :) glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.CountyId, 
    co.Description as County
from
    Application as a
        inner join
    Dictionary.Counties as co 
        on a.CountyId = co.Id
        inner join
    CountyCollaboration cc1
        on co.id = cc1.CountyId
        inner join
    CountyCollaboration cc2
        on cc1.CollaborationId = cc2.CollaborationId
where
    c2.CountyId = IsNull(@CountyId, @pHiddenCountyId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
CountryId = case when @counrtyid is null then CountryId else @CounrtyId end
```